# Android app does not start on Android 4.3

Tags: bug, status-declined, android-app

I've just updated my Samsung Galaxy S II GT-i9100 (International) to run the (admittedly "nightly") version of CyanogenMod 10.2 (20130905-NIGHTLY) which is based on Android 4.3 (kernel 3.0.64), and every time I launch the Stack Exchange app, I get a white screen with the "Stack exchange" header and then the standard "Unfortunately, Stack Exchange has stopped [Report/Ok]".

Package name: com.stackexchange.marvin
Package version :35
Package version name: 0.1.25

Yes, I know I'm running an alpha version of SE on an "alpha" version of CyanogenMod, but looking to the future here!

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus (unmodded) with an official version of Android 4.3. I will try it there.

Comment: Just tried uninstalling and reinstalling the SE app and it is working again. Odd that this was the only non Google app to have a problem (wonder if it was connected to my Google login)

Answer (score 9):

The app is crashing with a `SecurityException` because of not having a necessary permission. Here's the thing: It *does* have that permission. So either you have disabled certain permissions, which – at least for the time being – is not a use case we support, or this is just a CM alpha issue, which we don't and will not ever support.

Comment: FWIW,  I'm running my app on my S III  with CyanogenMod 4.3 nightlies with no apparent effects.